# Docker compose with GitHub actions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I am using `docker/build-push-action@v2` action in my GitHub actions file to build and push docker images to the GitHub package registry. Building and pushing `Dockerfile` is working for me.

I have `docker-compose` file which I want to build and push to the GitHub registry.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert but at first glance it looks like that action might have been built with a single docker container in mind.

Since you're using Docker Compose maybe an action like this could be better? https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-actions-workflow